# Can I use state AND props for control between parent/child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm in the process of learning React/redux - Fantastic framework, didn't know JS counl be this cool!!!

My question...

I have a parent component and a child. The child can be hidden/shown in to ways:

1. press a button on the child to hide it
2. press a button on the parent to show/hide

1) can be controlled by use of this.state 
2) can be controlled by setting a prop from the parent

My problem is that I can't control the child with State AND props, as I see it it is state OR props.

(it is not entirely true. I can use the event componentWillReceiveProps - is this the way to go. I.e. primarily use state, but transfer between props and state with the event)

Open to other good suggestions

Thanks

__EDIT____________EDIT_________EDIT___________EDIT___________

Just read the [FB docu](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) again, and guess that my suggestion is the recommended way:

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to
>   prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props
>   and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in
>   this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass state and a function from the parent to the child as a prop. This function can be used to toggle the state. You can use this function in both the parent and child.

Example:

```
// parent
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './path/to/child';

class ParentComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
    }

    state = {
        isVisible: false;
    }

    handleToggle(current) {
        this.setState({
            isVisible: !current
        })
    }

    render(){
        <div>
            <ChildComponent handleToggle={this.handleToggle} isVisible={this.state.isVisible} />
            <button onClick={(isVisible) => this.handleToggle(this.state.isVisible)}>Toggle me</div>
        </div>
    }
}

export default ParentComponent;


// child
import React from 'react';

const ChildComponent = ({ isVisible, handleToggle }) => {
    return (
        <button onClick={(isVisible) => handleToggle(isVisible)}>Toggle me</div>
    );
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks @patrick slick... I'm already paying the function... Just had not thought about using it on both sides